# Warning window with timer

Tags: dialog-window

I'm deploying a package to consumers to test out that isn't complete and ready to use yet, just so they can give me feedback on usability and do feature requests. While doing so I want it to be clear to them that this is not ready for use, so I added this to popup before the program runs:

```
DialogInput[{TextCell[
   "This program is incomplete and not intended for use in research 
papers, only for testing user friendliness.", FontSize -> 14, 
   FontWeight -> Bold],
  Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[], 
   Enabled -> Dynamic[Clock[1, 3, 1] == 1]]
  }
 ]
```

Now I set a Clock so that way they can't exit it too fast and it makes them more likely to read the warning. However there is still the "X" in the top right corner, is there any way to create a window in which that isn't there?
Below I've attached a screenshot of the window for clarity.
[image]

Comment: Look at the `WindowFrameElements` options

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `WindowFrameElements` and "PrettyProgressBar" for the win:

```
c = 0; CreateWindow[
 DialogNotebook[{TextCell[
    "This program is incomplete and not intended for use in research papers,   
     only for testing user friendliness.", FontSize -> 14, 
    FontWeight -> Bold],
   ResourceFunction["PrettyProgressBar"][Dynamic[1 - c], Appearance -> "Barber", 
     Background -> Lighter@Gray, ImageSize -> 340],
   DefaultButton["I UNDERSTAND", DialogReturn[], 
     Enabled -> Dynamic[(c = Clock[1, 3, 1]) == 1]]}], 
 WindowFrameElements -> {}, WindowTitle -> "Warning!",  WindowSize -> {350, 120}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, like most things, notebook options such as WindowFrameElements doesn’t work in the cloud.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and fixes that my clock was taking ~10 seconds instead of the specified 3.  Thank you!